# switch case with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation, switch-statement

Hi everyboby i'm just trying to validate some inputs and textareas with javascript using a switch, but it seems to not be working properly, my function which calls **validarorden** looks like this.

```
function validarorden(){
    var validado = true;

    var tipo = document.getElementById("cmbTipoEquipo").value; //select
    var marca = document.getElementById("cmbMarcaEquipo").value; //select
    var modelo = document.getElementById("txtModeloEquipo").value; //input
    var nserie = document.getElementById("txtNSerieEquipo").value; //input
    var descripcion = document.getElementById("txtaReparacion").value; //textarea

    //next alert shows '0 - 0 - - -' when I click on the button for the fisrt time 
    alert(tipo+" - "+marca+" - "+modelo+" - "+nserie+" - "+descripcion);

    switch(tipo) {
        case 0:
            alert("debes elegir el tipo");
            validado = false;
        break;
    }

    switch(marca) {
        case 0:
            alert("debes elegir la marca");
            validado = false;
        break;
    }

    switch(modelo.length) {
        case 0:
            alert("debes ingresar el modelo");
            validado = false;
        break;
    }

    switch(nserie.length) {
        case 0:
            alert("debes ingresar el numero de serie");
            validado = false;
        break;
    }

    switch(descripcion) {
        case (descripcion.length == 0):
            alert("debes ingresar la descripcion");
            validado = false;
        break;
        case (descripcion.length > 200):
            alert("la descripcion no debe ser mayor a 200");
            validado = false;
        break;
        case (descripcion.length < 50):
            alert("la descripcion debe ser de al menos 50");
            validado = false;
        break;

    }

    return validado;
}
```

I call this function with a jquery event.

```
$("body").on("click","#btnGenerarOrden",function(){
        if(validarorden()) {
            alert("Correcto");
        }
    });
```

The cases of **modelo** and **nserie** variables work fine but not the rest of them, HTML code is next.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="form-group fltipo">
     <label class="control-label" for="cmbTipoEquipo">Tipo</label>
     <select id="cmbTipoEquipo" class="form-control">
     <option value="0">Tipo</option>
     <option value="1">Latop</option>
     </select>
   </div>
</div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="form-group flmarca">
           <label class="control-label" for="cmbMarcaEquipo">Marca</label>
           <select id="cmbMarcaEquipo" class="form-control">
           <option value="0">marca</option>
           <option value="1">HP</option>
           </select>
        </div>                        
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
       <div class="form-group flmodelo">
           <label class="control-label" for="txtModeloEquipo">Modelo</label>
           <input type="text" id="txtModeloEquipo" class="form-control">
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
       <label class="control-label" for="txtNSerieEquipo">N.Serie</label>
       <div class="input-group flnserie">
       <input type="text" id="txtNSerieEquipo" class="form-control">
       <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="btnAutoNS" type="button"><span class="glyphicon 
glyphicon-random"></span></button>
       </span>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
       <div class="form-group fldescr">  
           <label class="control-label" for="txtaReparacion">Descripción de la reparación</label>
           <textarea class="form-control" id="txtaReparacion" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea>
       </div>
      </div>
```

I hope you guys can help me

Comment: I suggest if statements over switch statements here

Comment: Put double quotes around the case 0 ... so case: "0"

Answer (score 0):

What you have to realize here is that a switch case statement uses the === comparator.  This means that the types of the variables being compared has to be the same.  So comparing the `xxxxx.length` to `0` is ok because length returns an integer.

However comparing the value of a select element returns a string so you need to put quotes around the 0 like so
`case "0":`

You could also use `switch (parseInt(xxx))` to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

In any Imperative programming language that includes `switch` functionality, the constant you're testing after the `case` statement must either be a constant, an expression that produces a constant (like a getter), or a string literal.

Your main problem is where you try to apply a switch statement to a boolean:

```
switch(descripcion) {
    case (descripcion.length == 0):
        alert("debes ingresar la descripcion");
        validado = false;
    break;
    case (descripcion.length > 200):
        alert("la descripcion no debe ser mayor a 200");
        validado = false;
    break;
    case (descripcion.length < 50):
        alert("la descripcion debe ser de al menos 50");
        validado = false;
    break;
}
```

In this section of your code, you try to test true or false statements. You should write an if/else if block to test the length values.

Using a switch statement this way would be like asking,

> Is the information in the text-box equal to the length greater than 200?

It just doesn't make any sense.

Another problem you have is comparing strings to constants. The `value` property of an input-field is type `String`, which means that you need to get the length of `field.value` to compare it to a constant, like this:

```
switch (tipo.length) {
    case 0:
        ...
    break;
}
```

Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Switch_statement for the complete list of rules for switch statements.